# Automatic Bash script to mount filesystem from vdi file

Tags: bash, shell, hex

I am attempting to mount a filesystem that is contained inside a VirtualBox vdi file. I cannot find the offset to use so I want to write a bash script that increments a variable until the system can successfully mount the file system.

I will be using the command
`mount -o loop,offset=0x01 file.vdi mountpoint` syntax.

In my bash script, I have a variable called `i` that is initially assigned the value `i="0x0"` and then each time through the loop I want to increment the value by one byte.

How do I do that in the bash scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ((i = 1;; ++i)); do
    offset=$(printf '0x%x' "$i")
    mount -o loop,offset="$offset" file.vdi mountpoint && break
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
i=0x0
while true; do
((i++))
opt=0x$(echo "obase=16; $i" | bc)
mount -o loop,offset="$opt" file.vdi mountpoint
break
#this is a dummy break;use condition to break from loop;
done
```